# Finding "USA" in cell and return next 6 number

Tags: excel

I have a long column "A" of cells with string of ID numbers. I would like a second column "B" to return ID numbers that begins with "USA" after the USA there is 6 numbers.

e.g. USA949223

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("USA",A1),9)
```

Comment: For OP: If string does not have `USA` you can nest the provided formula here inside `IFERROR` like so: `IFERROR([above formula], "USA Not Found")`